# Finishing a corollary in Tao's proof of Banach Tarski

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory

This is the proof I'm referring to: [https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/Expository/banach-tarski.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/preprints/Expository/banach-tarski.pdf)

I understand how we prove Corollary 1.2 and Lemma 1.3:

> Corollary 1.2 (Hausdorff paradox, first version). There exists a countable subset $C$ of the sphere $S^2$, and a decomposition
> $$
> \left(S^2 \backslash C\right)=\Omega_1 \uplus \Omega_2 \uplus \Omega_3 \uplus \Omega_4
> $$
> such that
> $$
> \left(S^2 \backslash C\right)=\Omega_1 \uplus A \Omega_2=\Omega_3 \uplus B \Omega_4
> $$
> for some rotation matrices $A, B \in S O(3)$.

> Lemma 1.3. Let $C$ be a countable subset of the sphere $S^2$. Then there exists a decomposition
> $$
> S^2=\Sigma_1 \uplus \Sigma_2
> $$
> such that
> $$
> S^2 \backslash C=\Sigma_1 \uplus R \Sigma_2
> $$
> for some rotation matrix $R \in S O(3)$.

However, Tao then writes that using these two results we can conclude 1.4.

> Corollary 1.4. There exists a partition
> $$
> S^2=\Gamma_1 \uplus \ldots \uplus \Gamma_8
> $$
> and rotation matrices $R_1, \ldots, R_8 \in S O(3)$ such that
> $$
> S^2=\biguplus_{i=1}^4 R_i \Gamma_i=\biguplus_{i=5}^8 R_i \Gamma_i
> $$

I was having difficulty showing how this follows from the above. How do we construct $\Gamma_i$ and $R_i$?